# Is changing root namespace in .net a bad idea?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, namespaces

I have a project split out accross multiple DLL's, mainly to keep things a bit more organised and stick to some separation. I was considering changing the root namespace to the same thing for all projects just to make things easier but this (old) article suggests its not a common practice but gives no reason as to why not.

[Understanding and Using Assemblies and Namespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973231.aspx)

> Unless you have a good reason for such an arrangement, though, it's best to keep things simple with one namespace per assembly and vice versa.

Is a 'good reason' in such a case where you want to organise things along these lines?

Project  / Namespace

```
1. Core (interfaces) / CompanyName
2. CommonServices / CompanyName.Services
4. XYZProcess / CompanyName.XYZ
5. XYZViews / ComapnyName.Views
6. etc
```

Comment: For me it makes completely sense to do it this way

Comment: Me too, I can't see any major downfall so wondered if I'm missing something.

Comment: Since root namespace doesn't apply to C#, you should probably remove that tag.  In a VB project, I always clear the root namespace from the project properties and use the Namespace statement explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The primary benefit to having the same name for the assembly as for the namespace is when your project grows very large, and you or some other engineer on your team doesn't remember where a particular class lives.  Simply by hovering over the class and seeing the namespace, you are given a hint about what assembly this class lives in.  But this isn't a hard-and-fast rule.  If your project is small enough that you always remember where everything lives then a single namespace is fine, and there are legitimate reasons for sharing a namespace across assemblies.

Answer (score 0):

In my company We have something like this:

- ProjectName.Core.Infrastructure
- ProjectName.Core.Services

And those are project names.
In my opinion it is better to name project (in bigger solution) correctly.
Is is easier to navigate during development process.

Comment: I guess that makes more sense thinking about it. I'm being lazy wanting to avoid long project names but I guess that would just add complexity trying to navigate/find where stuff is.

Comment: the_lotus - yes they can, but the question is if they should be :)